# How do i create a heatmap from two columns plus the value of those two in python

Tags: python, heatmap

and thank you for helping!

I would like to generate a heatmap in python, from the data df. 
(i am using pandas, seaborn, numpy, and matplotlib in my project)

The dataframe df looks like:

```
index | a | b | c | year | month
0     |   |   |   | 2013 |   1
1     |   |   |   | 2015 |   4
2     |   |   |   | 2016 |   10 
3     |   |   |   | 2017 |   1
```

in the dataset the rows are each a ticket.

The dataset is big (51 colums and 100k+ rows), 
 so a, b, c is just to show some random columns. (for month => 1 = jan, 2= feb...)

*For the heatmap:*

```
x-axis = year,
y-axis = month,
```

value: and in the heatmap, I wanted the value between the two axes to be a count of the number of rows, in which a ticket has been given in that year and month.

The result I imagine should look something like the from the seaborn documentation:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/_images/seaborn-heatmap-4.png

I am new to coding and tried a lot of random things I found on the internet and has not been able to make it work.

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Once you have attempted to write some code to solve your problem we would be happy to help with any issues or questions you may have, but StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Having people write code for you is not conducive to learning, you will do better to struggle through some examples on your own before having people answer questions for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do (with generated data):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import random

y = [random.randint(2013,2017) for n in range(2000)]
m = [random.randint(1,12) for n in range(2000)]


df = pd.DataFrame([y,m]).T
df.columns=['y','m']
df['count'] = 1
df2 = df.groupby(['y','m'], as_index=False).count()
df_p = pd.pivot_table(df2,'count','m','y')


sns.heatmap(df_p)
```

You probably won't need the column `count` but I added it because I needed an extra column for the `groupby` to work.

Comment: Thank you for the help, 
I realize by your example, that the problem I had was then I extracted the columns I would also get the index number and then I couldn’t create the heatmap.

Comment: I'm glad it helped !